# Kivy - TextInput on_focus behavior issue

Tags: python, kivy

I'm creating an app using kivy. So I don't think I'm understanding something correctly regarding the on_focus behavior of the FloatInput.

Let me first describe what I'm trying to do here. I'm trying to activate a pop-up numpad when the user clicks on a TextInput (this numpad just has buttons for numbers 0-9 and an "enter" button). Next, once the user provides a number in the pop-up numpad and hits an "enter" button, the pop-up should close and the text field of the TextInput should be updated to the user entered number.

However, I'm running into a problem. Essentially, I have a form with multiple TextInputs constructed as described above (I'll refer to them hereafter as "FloatInputs" b/c that's what I've named them). The first time I enter values into one of the FloatInputs, everything works as expected. But the problem occurs whenever I try to enter a number into a second FloatInput. Specifically, the on_focus function is called twice somehow and the user must enter the value into the pop-up twice as a result (this is obviously not ideal as it would serve to frustrate the user).

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I've been puzzled by it for quite a while. I think the heart of the problem lies in the order of the focusing of the TextInput and the popup widgets, but I could be wrong here. If someone could please offer suggestions as to how I could fix this bug I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here is the relevant python code:

```
class FloatInput(TextInput):

    def on_focus(self, instance, value):

        print 'ON FOCUS CALLED - THIS SHOULD ONLY BE CALLED ONCE!'

        # Adding this helped part of the problem (however, on_focus is still being called twice???)
        self.unfocus_on_touch = False

        prompt_content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')      # Main layout

        num_pad = NumPadWidget()
        prompt_content.add_widget(num_pad)

        def my_callback(instance):

            self.text = num_pad.ids.num_label.text
            self.popup.dismiss()

        # Now define the popup, with the content being the layout:
        self.popup = Popup(id='num_pad_popup', title='Enter value', content=prompt_content, size_hint=(0.8,0.5), autodismiss=False)

        num_pad.ids.enter_btn.bind(on_press=my_callback)

        # Open the pop-up:
        self.popup.open()
```

And here is the relevant kv code:

```
<NumPadButton@Button>:
    font_size: '16dp'
    bold: True

<NumPadWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 1
            id: num_label
            Label:
                id: num_label
                text: ''
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 5
            orientation: 'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '7'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '7'
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '8'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '8'
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '9'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '9'
            BoxLayout:
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '4'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '4'
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '5'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '5'
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '6'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '6'
            BoxLayout:
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '1'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '1'
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '2'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '2'
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '3'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '3'
            BoxLayout:
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '0'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '0'
                NumPadButton:
                    text: '.'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text + '.'
                NumPadButton:
                    text: 'del'
                    on_press:
                        num_label.text = num_label.text[:-1]
            BoxLayout:
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    NumPadButton:
                        text: 'C'
                        on_press:
                            num_label.text = ''
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_x: 2
                    NumPadButton:
                        id: enter_btn
                        text: 'Enter'
```

Comment: The very first sentence should end with TextInput and not FloatInput. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after playing with this a bit more I found a solution to achieve the functionality that I wanted. However, to be clear this does resolve why the on_focus behavior is acting in the manner that I've described in my original post.

Here is a work around in case anyone is interested:

```
class FloatInput(TextInput):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):

            prompt_content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')      # Main layout

            num_pad = NumPadWidget()
            prompt_content.add_widget(num_pad)

            def my_callback(instance):
                self.text = num_pad.ids.num_label.text
                self.popup.dismiss()

            # Now define the popup, with the content being the layout:
            self.popup = Popup(id='num_pad_popup', title='Enter value', content=prompt_content, size_hint=(0.8,0.5), autodismiss=False)
            num_pad.ids.enter_btn.bind(on_press=my_callback)

            # Open the pop-up:
            self.popup.open()
```

Specifically, this solution works by using on_touch_down instead of looking for the focus of the TextInput. Additionally, looking for the collision with "if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)" prevents an error where all widgets of the same type respond to the user touch.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: In recent builds, the on_touch_down method is called with two parameters. The first positional parameter (other then self) is the instance of the object, on which the touch occurred. Where as the second parameters is the touch event object.

Comment: If you consumed touch event, then you should return True to stop propagation I guess.

Comment: Could you provide the full working code so I can see the functionality you describe? I have a similar problem and wanted to see how it might integrate with my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the on_focus() method of TextInput looks like this:

```
def on_focus(self, instance, value, *largs):
```

If value is **True**, it's a focus event. If it's **False**, then it's a defocus/blur event. I really don't know why they used one handler for both events but they implemented it this way. I think anyone else would have implemented this as on_focus()/on_blur().

This could be the reason why a method might be firing off twice.

Comment: Finally i found the reason for so many strange things happening in my app! One should make an if value ... else ... codeblock and put the code that should run on focus into the if part and the things that should happen on the previous widget on defocussing in the else part.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but...

The solution is to test the value. If it's True, it's a focus event. If it's False, it's a defocus event.

```
def on_focus(self, instance, value):
    if value:
        print("focusing in...")
    else:
        print("defocusing")
```

And here's how to do it in a .kv file:

```
TextInput:
    on_focus:
        if self.focus: print("focusing in...")
        else: print("defocusing")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to call up a modal after clicking on a text input. It would fire twice if I tried using `on_focus`. What worked for me was to set `is_focusable = False` and use the `on_touch_down` event to fire the function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your TextInputs (in your case 'FloatInput') have the widget property **unfocus_on_touch** set to **False** as soon as possible in your code. That means in a kv file, factory builder string (below) or some wrapped `__init__` class function. Setting this property in the **on_focus** event is too late and probably causes it to get fired twice.

```
Builder.load_string('''
<RootWidget>:
    TextInput:
        unfocus_on_touch: False
        id: id_textbox
        text: 'hello world'
        multiline: False
        font_size: 20
''')
```